# Apollo Graphql useQuery will not work unless I declare data as empty object

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am working with apollo and graphql and the following will not work, it gives me an (...)(...).data is undefined error.

```
const { 
    data: { getPost } 
  } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      postId
    }
  });
```

Here is FETCH_POST_QUERY

```
    const FETCH_POST_QUERY = gql`
    query ($postId:ID!){
        getPost(postId:$postId){
            id 
            body 
            createdAt 
            username 
            likeCount 
            likes {            
                username
            }
            commentCount
            comments{
                id 
                username 
                createdAt 
                body
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

However if I declare data as an empty object as shown below everything works fine.

```
const { 
    data: { getPost } = {}
  } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      postId
    }
  });
```

Elsewhere in my code, where I fetch multiple posts instead of one I use useQuery as follows with no issues.

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

FETCH_POSTS_QUERY :

```
export const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    getPosts {
      id
      body
      createdAt
      username
      likeCount
      likes {
        username
      }
      commentCount
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
        body
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

My question is why do I need to initially declare data as an empty object in the first case, but not in the second case. If you need the Post Schemas and typedefs from my backed please let me know and I'll edit this post.

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: decompose/destructure/access nested data props after loading

Comment: allright thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you call an apollo react hook, `data` can be undefined as the query/mutation can throw an error, or even not return data at all.

The problem is that you're destructuring from `data` here:

```js
const { data: { getPost } } = useQuery...
```

Initially, while the query is being executed, `data` is undefined, and the process tries to access undefined.getPost, wich throws an Error.

When you do `{ data: { getPost } = {} }`, you're specifying that if `data` is undefined, then set it's value to `{}`. When the process tries to access {}.getPost works, (but `{}.getPost === undefined`).

It's not recommended to double-destructure fields from data that could be undefined. One of the best ways to handle these is the following:

```js
const { data } = useQuery...;

handleSomething() {
  if(data) { // to prevent undefined data
    // do something
  }
}
```

--

In the second example it works because when you try to access `data.something`, `data` isn't `undefined` no more.

Comment: Allright, that makes sense, thank you and xadm for clearing this up for me